# memory leak during char* manipulation

Tags: c, string, char

I do something like that in the loop :

```
char* test = "\0";

test = strcat(test, somestr);
...
char* tmp = strstr(test, 0, len);

free(test);
test = tmp;
```

And get memory leak. What I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why does this code crash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437318/why-does-this-code-crash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have a memory leak (in the code you posted anyway), but you do several things wrong.

```
char* test = "\0";
```

This declares pointer named *test* and initializes it to point to some literal array of two bytes { 0, 0 }

```
test = strcat(test, somestr);
```

This tries to append something to the end of that string literal (and since as a C string it is empty it would be like a string copy).  Literal values often are stored in memory that is not writable, so copying something into this memory would likely cause an error (segmentation fault or SIGSEGV on many operating systems).  Additionally you only have two bytes of storage pointed to by *test*, which means that unless *somestr* refers to a string whose *strlen* is less than or equal to 1 you would end up attempting to write over some other memory (whatever happens to be after the "\0" that *test* points to).

```
char* tmp = strstr(test, 0, len);
```

I don't know what is going on here since *strstr* only takes 2 arguments (both of them `const char *`).

```
free(test);
```

Here you are attempting to free non-heap allocated memory.  The heap is where malloc, realloc, and calloc get the memory they allocate.  Calling *free* with a memory location that was not returned by one of these functions (and a few other functions on some systems) is an error because *free* does not know what to do with them.

You should probably keep in mind that often memory is huge array of bytes, and that the pointers you use are like array indexes.  The system you are using may be able to distinguish between some areas of this array and determine how you can access them (readable, writable, and/or executable).  But it is still just an array of bytes.  When you have a string (such as `"foo"`) that means that somewhere in RAM there are four bytes ( 3 letters + the \0 terminator byte) and you can access this area by knowing its index within the array of bytes that is RAM.  There are likely other things that are stored adjacent to your string (such as `{ ..., 4, 2, 'f', 'o', 'o', 0, 99, 3, 2, ...}`) so you have to try to make sure you stay within the space of that memory without wandering into the adjacent data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems:

1. `strcat` will append a string to the destination buffer.  You need the first parameter to be a buffer not a string literal pointer.  Here is an example of a char buffer or also called an array of chars: `char test[1024];`
2. The return value of `strcat` is a pointer to the destination buffer, it is not a newly allocated string on the heap.  So you shouldn't call `free` on the return value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `strcat` to `test` because you are initially pointing it to a constant `char *`. You need to assign memory for it. `strcat` won't do it.

Change your code to something like:

```
char* test = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
test[0] = '\0'; // nothing on this string to begin with
strcat(test, "something");
free(test);
```

Also, this won't work:

```
char* tmp = strcat(test, 0, len);
```

Since there is no `strcat` function with three parameters.

Remember. 99.9% of the time there will be a `free` call for each `malloc` allocation.

Comment: Then I have one more question. How can I remove last k elements from buffer?

Comment: In C strings, you don't "remove" last elements - you move the '\0' end marker to terminate the string at the new position.

Comment: How can I do it ? By the way I acctually have a string in unicode format. Does it mean that I need to calculate not the length of the string but the last usefull byte and put '\0' after it?